# How to find the combination of words that includes all the letters in the input with Python

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, optimization, modeling

I want to find the most efficient way to loop through the combination of letters that are entered in Python and return a set of words whose combination includes all the letters, if feasible.

Example:

Say user entered A B C D E. Goal is to find the least number of words that includes all the letters. In this case an optimum solution, in preference order, will be:

1. One word that has all 5 letters
2. Two words that has all the 5 letters. (can be 4-letter word + 1-letter word OR 3 letter word + 2 letter word. Does not make difference)

.... 
etc.

If no match, then find go back to 1. with n-1 letters etc.

I have a function to check if a "combination of letters" (i.e. word) is in dictionary.

```
def is_in_lib(word):
    if word in lib:
        return word
    return False
```

Ideal answer should not include finding the combination of those letters and searching all of those. Searching through my dictionary is very costly, so I need something that can take also optimize the time that we search through the dictionary

IMPORTANT EDIT: The order matters and continuity is required. Meaning if user enters "H", "T", "A", you cannot build "HAT".

Real Example: If the input is : T - H - G - R - A - C - E - K - B - Y - E " output should be "Grace" and "Bye"

Comment: How do you handle multiplicity? Eg: The users gives two 'A's and 4 different letters?

Comment: I don't think your approach is feasible. The number of combinations grows too fast, and checking each possible combination would take a huge amount of time even for small sets of letters. If you provide more context probably someone can come up with a smarter solution for what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I just edited @fodma1 . Since the order matters, multiplicity will not be an issue. (You will need to use all)

Comment: @bakuriu you a right that's why I don't want to go from that path. Example: If the input is : T - H - G - R - A - C - E - K - B - Y - E " output should be "Grace" and "Bye"

Comment: @PaulMiles Isn't "grace" and "they" better than "grace" and "bye"? The former still preserves ordering, but not contiguity. Is contiguity also required?

Comment: @fmc, right continuity is required as well.

Comment: @PaulMiles What principle should guide the algorithm when the search to match all N letters fails and we begin searching for a match against N-1 letters. Is the algorithm free to drop any one of the N letters, or should it drop a specific letter (e.g., the first or last)? In other words, does the algorithm also have to respect the contiguity of the user's input when going from the N search to the N-1 search, to N-2, etc. BTW, you should add another edit to the question emphasizing the contiguity requirement as well as ordering -- both matter a lot.

Comment: Why the output should be `grace` and `bye` in your example? Shouldn't the words include *all* the letters? `grace` and `bye` miss `thk`. Otherwise I think what you wrote is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key idea here would be to have some kind of index providing a mapping from a canonical sequence of characters to actual words. Something like that:

```
# List of known words
>>> words = ('bonjour', 'jour', 'bon', 'poire', 'proie')


# Build the index
>>> index = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for w in words:
...     index[''.join(sorted(w.lower()))].append(w)
...
```

This will produce a efficient way to find all the anagrams corresponding to a sequence of characters:

```
>>> index
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'joru': ['jour'], 'eiopr': ['poire', 'proie'], 'bjnooru': ['bonjour'], 'bno': ['bon']})
```

You could query the index that way:

```
>>> user_str = 'OIREP'
>>> index.get(''.join(sorted(user_str.lower())), "")
['poire', 'proie']
```

Of course, this will only find "exact" anagrams -- that is containing *all* the letters provided by the user. To find all the string that match a subset of the user provided string, you will have to remove one letter at a time and check again each combination. I feel like *recursivity* will help to solve that problem ;)

**EDIT:**
(should I put that on a *spoiler* section?)

Here is a possibl solution:

```
import collections

words = ('bonjour', 'jour', 'bon', 'or', 'pire', 'poire', 'proie')

index = collections.defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    index[''.join(sorted(w.lower()))].append(w)

# Recursively search all the words containing a sequence of letters
def search(letters, result = set()):
    # Assume "letters" ordered
    if not letters:
        return

    solutions = index.get(letters)
    if solutions:
        for s in solutions:
            result.add(s)

    for i in range(0,len(letters)):
        search(letters[:i]+letters[i+1:], result)

    return result


# Use case:
user_str = "OIREP"

s = search(''.join(sorted(user_str.lower())))
print(s)
```

Producing:

```
set(['poire', 'or', 'proie', 'pire'])
```

It is not *that bad*, but could be improved since the same subset of characters are examined several times. This is especially true is the user provided search string contain several identical letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a string/list from the input letters, and iterate trought THEM on every word in the word library:

```
    inputstring='abcde'
    for i in lib:
            is_okay=True
            for j in inputstring:
                    if i.find(j)=-1:
                            is_okay=False
            if is_okay:
                    return i
```

I think the other cases (two words with 3-2 letters) can be implemented recursively, but it couldn't be efficient.